# Why does my docker bind mount shows some error and does not load port?

Tags: docker

I am going through a tutorial on docker and I came across this while I am trying it on my own(Actually I am following the same examples as it is in tutorial) the guide uses MacOs while I use Windows.

Following are the files

Docker-file:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Folder structure

[image: Folder Structure of the file i am working]

Tool used -VS code

**image name= feedback-node**

**container name: feedback-container**

**volume name: feedback-volume**

project file path :

```
E:\downloads\Compressed\data-volumes-01-starting-setup>
```

while creating the container with the named volume I am getting the following output

Terminal command used:

```
PS E:\downloads\Compressed\data-volumes-01-starting-setup> docker run -d -p 3000:80 --name feedback-container -v feedback-volume:/app/feedback  feedback-node
```

```
PS E:\downloads\Compressed\data-volumes-01-starting-setup> docker run -d -p 3000:80 --name feedback-container -v feedback-volume:/app/feedback  feedback-node
c6476ae44c400e802d6e26f87021507f0c5184cf34e6ecccddbc05d4c878ab6c
PS E:\downloads\Compressed\data-volumes-01-starting-setup>
```

[image: This is the required output]

I am having trouble with bind mount I find  that the output is not produced in the server

Terminal command used:

```
PS E:\downloads\Compressed\data-volumes-01-starting-setup> docker run -d -p 3000:80 --name feedback-container -v feedback:/app/feedback -v E:\downloads\Compressed\data-volumes-01-starting-setup:/app  feedback-node
```

while running docker logs following output displayed

When I do named-volume the program gets executed whereas when I do BINDMOUNT and refresh the port it says the Site cant be reached if you see the docker logs details (picture attached) it says "Cannot find module express".

[image]
[image: output while running the bindmount]

Comment: I have no idea of how node JS how it works as well. i think the problem is with node js

Comment: I might suggest learning one technology at a time; if you want to learn Node, [install Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and use it without involving Docker at all.  The Docker documentation has its own tutorial series and [Containerize an application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) uses a simple Node app.  Volumes should _not_ be part of your setup.

Comment: This having been said, it's a little unclear from your question what's going wrong.  You might read through [ask] in the SO Help Center for some tips on writing a clear question.  For example, it would help to say at the beginning of the question what the specific problem is, and if the HTML and CSS files aren't needed as part of a [mcve] you can delete them from the question.  Make sure to include your log output as plain text and not an image file.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze sorry for making it difficult for you, I am new to stack overflow. Since I am focusing on docker, the instructor in the tutorial is using node.js for storing feedback inputs since I am new to docker I just replicated the steps he was doing to get the hang of the terminal commands etc. The issue is that when I do **named-volume** the program gets executed whereas when I do BINDMOUNT and refresh the port it says the **Site cant be reached** if you see docker logs details (picture attached) it says "Cannot find module express". HTML and CSS are just for reference.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to remove the unnecessary content and replace the image file with the plain-text logs.  Based on what you've said so far, neither named volumes nor bind mounts seem like they should be part of your container setup; they are to hold persistent _data_, but the _code_ should normally be built into your image via the Dockerfile.